# Why do I have to change a minimum of 6 characters if I want to edit a post?

Tags: discussion, editing

When I want to correct a spelling mistake and I only have to change a few characters, the website tells me I have to change a minimum of six characters.

Why is this required? I could always edit the question to fit it, but when it's only a short question with only one small spelling mistake, I would have to rewrite half of the question only to send the edit.

I think the minimum number should be dropped to 1 character, so everyone can help correcting single mistakes.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better for for meta.SE?

Comment: @falstro I am quite new to SE, so yes you may be right.

Comment: See: [What is the reason behind the 6 character minimum for suggested edits?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251580/3511560) and [Change this behavior to allow for spelling corrections and the like: “Edits must be at least 6 characters”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82534/257476)

Comment: @fooot Thank you, thats good.